# Python multiprocessing and auto py to exe

Tags: python, multiprocessing, auto-py-to-exe

I am currently working on a random characters generator which use multiprocessing to accelerate the process. I use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

to avoid the whole code to run multiple time, but whenever I use auto py to exe to compile it and run it, it just runs the code multiple times.

How could I avoid that?

Thanks!

Comment: did you call [`multiprocessing.freeze_support()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) directly after `if __name__ == "__main__"`?

Comment: no, i did not. what does it do ?

Comment: It is required for "freezing" your script to an executable (on Windows). IIRC it fixes the way command line args are passed to the child processes so they don't think they are also "main"